# send parameter along url angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am working on project where my role is server-side programmer.Client side developer used Angular js while designing pages.

Problem I am facing is we have one page where I need to pass one parameter along with url to server

```
<a  id="startQuiz" href="#/Quiz" >Start Quiz</a>
```

jquery code is

```
$('#startQuiz').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     window.location.href = '#/Quiz/' + selectedTopic; 
}
```

Controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Quiz", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
      public String Quiz(HttpServletRequest request,Model model,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(value = "topic", required = false) String topic) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("select topic : "+topic);

}
```

I am getting topic as null cause Nothing after the hash # sign is getting sent to the server, hence the null values

Rounting file Is

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
     .when("/Quiz", {templateUrl: "Quiz", controller: "PageCtrl"})
});
```

So, What change should I make in routing so I can get value of topic in Controller
Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the page is not what matters here. That URL will only load the main page template.

What matters is the URL used to send the AJAX request to your backend controller.

The route should be defined as

```
$routeProvider
 .when("/Quiz/:topicId", {
      templateUrl: "Quiz", 
      controller: "PageCtrl"
 })
```

Then, using the $routeParams service in the PageCtrl, you can get the value of topicId, and send the appropriate AJAX request to the backend.